# Initialized object that is in other object PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following object:

```
TYPE o_seat IS OBJECT
(
    seat_id VARCHAR2 (8 BYTE),
    seat_category_name VARCHAR2 (32 BYTE)
)
```

and the following objects :

```
 TYPE m_seats IS TABLE OF o_seat;


TYPE o_row IS OBJECT
(
    row_no NUMBER (2, 0),
    seats_array m_seats
)
```

I initialize object:

```
   v_row   o_row := o_row (NULL,NULL);
```

How can I initialize seats_array  in v_row?

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
o_row (12,m_seats(o_seat('x','y'),o_seat('y','z')) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
v_row   o_row := o_row (
                        '1',
                        m_seats(
                                o_seat('Seat1','Elite'),
                                o_seat('Seat2','Premium')
                                )
                        );
BEGIN

FOR I IN 1..v_row.seats_array.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row :'||v_row.row_no||
                            ' Seat: '||v_row.seats_array(I).seat_id||
                            ' Category: '||v_row.seats_array(I).seat_category_name);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```